# What's wrong with my pilea peperomioides?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care

I recently moved this little Pilea to a windowsill of a south-east facing window. This means it gets some direct morning sun, whereas before it was in a room with a skylight and only got indirect light. A few days after the move I suddenly noticed that my Pilea wasn't feeling very happy. The leaves droop; the newer leaves are curling inwards, the older curl outwards. Does this mean that its new location is too sunny? I'm confused, as I thought these plants like to have lots of light and morning sun was fine. The sun really isn't that strong here in Belgium.

[image]

[image]

[image]